# Laravel disable or enable prepare input for validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

How can we disable or enable `prepareForValidation` ?

If I have

```
public function A(TasksRequest $request) <-- no need prepareForValidation in TasksRequest ( disable )

public function B(TasksRequest $request) <-- need prepareForValidation in TasksRequest ( enable )
```

Answer (score 2):

Requests for your first interaction, this is purpose. So if you don't want to use validation change TasksRequest to Request.

**Update because of comment**

prepareFolValidation is method using in Requests. So if your prepareForValidation optional for different request please send key in $request then check this in prepareForValidation method.
Or (recommended) use different Request

**Update for second comment**

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    if(!request('disabled'))
    {
        $this->merge([
            'slug' => Str::slug($this->slug),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I make TasksRequest to manage code better for validation. I mean the question above, if I want to do validation in 2 different function, and in function B I want to merge data request from other data table, someone suggested using prepareForValidation. So how we can use prepareForValidation only in function B

Comment: I also think like that, create a unique key to check the use of prepareForValidation. But I'm trying to ask if there is a method to enable or disable prepareForValidation. 
I checked in document laravel no additional information for it.

Comment: hahaha I like your trick ideas. Thank you. Actually want to ask this to github laravel/framework, maybe it could be an additional feature to prepareForValidation can be disable/enable. but it must be closed immediately because there is no need.

Comment: Is this helps to you